# Create alias in derived class for method in base class with the same name in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, alias

I'm new to Python. Let's say that I have a `Parent` base class and a derived `Child` class that inherits from `Parent`:

```
class Parent():
    def foo(self):
        print('foo in Parent')
    def bar(self):
        print('bar in Parent')

class Child(Parent):
    pass

print(Child.__dict__)
print(Parent.__dict__)
```

The output is something like this:

```
# Child.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
# Parent.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', 'foo': <function Parent.foo at 0x104f76680>, 'bar': <function Parent.bar at 0x104f76710>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

My understanding is that `foo` and `bar` in `Parent` class are instance methods so they don't appear in `Child.__dict__`. This is how it works in order for `Child` class to be able to override those methods, please correct me if I'm wrong.

If i change `Child` class a little bit, by creating an alias named `foo` and assign it to method `foo` in `Parent` class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    foo = Parent.foo
```

I expect this to not work because `Child` already inherits all the members that `Parent` so it doesn't make sense that I can create another `foo` when one already exists.
But it works, if I create an object of type `Child` and call `foo` from it, it will print `foo in Parent`. And contents of `Child.__dict__` and `Parent.__dict__` now are:

```
Child.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', 'foo': <function Parent.foo at 0x1010ee680>, '__doc__': None}
Parent.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', 'foo': <function Parent.foo at 0x1010ee680>, 'bar': <function Parent.bar at 0x1010ee710>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

With `foo` method now in `Child.__dict__` at the same address of `0x1010ee680`.

Can someone walk me through what's going on here and is this something that one should do/avoid? Thank you!

Comment: Functions are first-class citizens in python, which means they are just like any other object. You assigned the function "object" `Parent.foo` which resides at `0x1010ee680` to the name `Child.foo`. So when you do anything with `Child.foo`, it's essentially doing that with `Parent.foo` because _they're the same object!_ Are you asking why `foo` didn't show up in the `Child.__dict__` in the first example, yet you're able to access it as `Child.foo`?

Comment: `foo = Parent.foo` doesn't create a new function. It only creates a new *name*  (attribute, specifically) referring to the existing function. In fact, as far as Python is concerned, there's little difference between `Child.foo` and `Parent.foo`; they're just two references to a `function` object sitting on the heap.

Comment: One could imagine a problem in a *multiple* inheritance hierarchy, where the existence of `Child.foo` could prevent a class from seeing an override of `Parent.foo` in other subclass of `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through this:

```py
class Parent():
    def foo(self):
        print('foo in Parent')
    def bar(self):
        print('bar in Parent')

class Child(Parent):
    pass

x = Parent()
x.foo()

y = Child()
y.foo()
```

When you say `x.foo`, Python first searches for a `foo` attribute in `x`'s own instance dict. It won't find any. Then, Python will search for a `foo` attribute in `x`'s class' dict, and as you already discovered, there is in indeed a `foo` in `Parent.__dict__`. Python will then construct a bound method whose `__func__` is `Parent.foo`. (Try `method = x.foo` and then `print(method.__func__)` or maybe `method()`. You will find that you also want to try `method.__func__(x)`.)

Now when you say `y.foo`, again the interpreter will find no `foo` attribute in `y`, and then it will go on to search for an attribute in `y`'s class. This time, there will be no attribute `foo` in `Child`, and then Python will look for the next class in `Child`'s method resolution order (or MRO; try `print(Child.__mro__)`). The next class is just `Child`'s parent class, which is `Parent`, and as we know, Python will find a `foo` attribute in `Parent`. Now you can try `y.foo.__func__` to see that it says `function Parent.foo`; this is `Parent`'s implementation of `foo`.

If you had that `foo = Parent.foo` line inside `Child`'s body, not much would change: the interpreter wouldn't have to walk down `Child`'s MRO chain to find `foo` (i.e. `foo` would be found right inside `Child`'s dict), but anyway the actual function object found would be the same: that's just `Parent.foo` again. (Try `Child.foo is Parent.foo`. This will be true with or without the `foo = Parent.foo` line.)

> This is how it works in order for Child class to be able to override those methods, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Yes, that's right. If instead of `foo = Parent.foo`, you had actually defined another function named `foo` in `Child`'s body, then the attribute named `foo` inside `Child`'s dict would be a different object from `Parent.foo`. This way, `y.foo` would again have no need to walk down the MRO all the way to `Parent`, because it would find a `foo` attribute right in `Child`, but this time this attribute would be `Child`'s own implementation of the `foo` method.